# query string apending after url in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i  have a anchor like:

```
<div class="fc-content cursor event_border' onclick="test(edate)"></div>
```

calling function is given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function test(id,evntDate)
   {
      var str = evntDate.toString();
      str = str.replace(/\//g,'');
      var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
      var url      = window.location.href; 
      var querystring ='?date='+str;
      window.location.replace(url+querystring);

   }
</script>
```

after this i am getting the url like:

```
localhost/abc/cde?date=2018-07-26
```

but when i click again on this url its returning me the query string like:

```
http://localhost/proflyt/dashboard?date=2018-07-26?date=2018-07-24
```

its not removing the first query string and returning me the url like so because of this i am not able to use my code further can anyone please help me related this ?? i am new in jquery i am stuck here not able to solve and not getting any kind of response please help me related this ..

Comment: `window.location.href` will include the query string. You can build the new URL from [the component parts of the location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) like `protocol`, `host`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just use origin and pathname instead href.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   function test(id,evntDate)
   {
      var str = evntDate.toString();
      str = str.replace(/\//g,'');
      var pathname = window.location.pathname;
      var ogigin      = window.location.ogigin; 
      var querystring ='?date='+str;
      var url = ogigin + pathname + querystring
      window.location.replace(url);

   }
</script>
```